# set path when file exists in Ansible yml code

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to set a var only when a file exists, here is one of my attempts

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - stat:
      path: '{{ srch_path_new }}/bin/run'
    register: result
  - vars: srch_path="{{ srch_path_new }}"
    when: result.stat.exists
```

This also didn't work

```
  - vars: srch_path:"{{ srch_path_new }}"
```

Comment: If something does not work, try to include the meaningful error. In this case, the reason why this does not work, is that `tasks` does not have `vars` value. Please look here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files for what the basic structure should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The task you are looking for is called [`set_fact:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/set_fact_module.html) and is the mechanism ansible uses to declare arbitrary "host variables", sometimes called "hostvars", or (also confusingly) "facts"

The syntax would be:

```
- set_fact:
    srch_path: "{{ srch_path_new }}"
  when: result.stat.exists
```

Also, while `vars:` **is** a legal keyword on a Task, its syntax is the same as `set_fact:` (or the `vars:` on the playbook): a yaml dictionary, **not** a `key:value` pair as you had. For example:

```
- debug:
    msg: hello, {{ friend }}
  vars:
    friend: Jane Doe
```

and be aware that `vars:` on a task exist *only for that task*